# Integrate with the Google Drive UI - add 2 parameters to the Open URL

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to add 2 parameters to the Open URL when i open file through Google Drive UI?
If not, Can I add those parameters to state parameter which i get with the redirected request?
public ActionResult Index(string state, string code)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add parameters to that redirect URI, sorry.

However, you can initiate the Authorization flow yourself (see in the developer console in Drive SDK, and uncheck "Automatically initiate the OAuth 2.0 flow when users open my application from Drive") This will allow you to use standard OAuth 2.0, where you can use the state parameter for whatever you like. This method will likely become the recommended way to authorize with open with.